# jQuery – Compounded variable from "each()"-function

Tags: jquery, string, checkbox, each

I'm failing at probably basic jQuery for returning a new compounded string (image src-paths) for every time an object is clicked.

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
    $(":checked").each(function(){
        var auswahl += $(this).attr('data-imagesrc');
    });

    alert(auswahl);
});
```

I'm later trying to send this string of image src-paths to a PHP-file to zip those images (the PHP-file zippes from an array of paths).
Unfortunately I'm not yet familiar with arrays if that would be a better solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `auswahl` is contained within the `each` scope meaning that you can't access it from outside of that function. Declare it outside.

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
    var auswahl = '';
    $(".check:checked").each(function(){
        auswahl += $(this).attr('data-imagesrc');
    });
    alert(auswahl);
});
```

To send info to the server try [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: How could I miss this… Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating values again and again after each click, you should set your variable to `''` before calling  `each` method. You can define your variable outside of your click handler and use `map` method which returns an array of values, please note that `:checkbox` selector is deprecated.

```
var auswahl;
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    auswahl = $(".check:checked").map(function(){
        return this.dataset.imagesrc
    }).get();
    alert(auswahl);
});
```

If you want to convert the array to a string you can use `join` method.

```
auswahl.join()
```

Comment: much as I'm a fan of `.map`, etc, I think it's overkill in this case.